# JavaScript login problems

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a simple HTML and JavaScript login but I don't know why it's unresponsive. Every time I run it my browser freaks out. Any advice at all would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

var names = ["MACK","KAV"];
var user = prompt("Please enter your username.").toUpperCase();

switch(user) {
case names[0]:
var password = prompt("Please enter your password.").toUpperCase();
   if(user === 'MACK' && password === 'ATTACK') {
    document.write("Hi Mack! Welcome back!");
}
else{
            for(i =0; i <0; i++) {
 document.write("Password not valid!!! ");
     };
};
    break;
    case names[1]:
var password = prompt("Please enter your password.").toUpperCase();
   if(user === 'KAV' && password === 'KAV') {
    document.write("Hello!");
}
else{
            for(i =0; i <0; i++) {
 document.write("Password not valid!!! ");
     };
};
    break;
default:
   for(i =0; i <0; i++) {
    document.write("Username not valid!!! ");
};
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `my browser freaks out` ?

Comment: What browser are you using? What's your OS?

Comment: It crashes my browser when you enter the wrong user name.

Comment: You've got a typo in the middle `for` loop, a missing semicolon after the condition. But even if you fix that none of your `for` loops will actually do anything because they all set `i` to `0` and then test if `i` is less than `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change all of your for statements to something like this:

```
for(i=0; i<1; i++){
    document.write("Password not Valid!!!")
}
```

This will print out "Password not Valid!!!" once. Right now your for statements do not allow it to be printed at all, because then can never be true.

Comment: Wow! That fixed it, thanks! I guess I never realized that I made my initial for loop settings impossible. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I made, you can check it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ux0ohvws/

```
var names = ["MACK","KAV"];
var user = prompt("Please enter your username.").toUpperCase();

switch(user) {
case names[0]:
    var password = prompt("Please enter your password.").toUpperCase();
    if(user === 'MACK' && password === 'ATTACK') {
        alert("Hi Mack! Welcome back!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Password not valid!!! ");
    }
    break;
case names[1]:
    var password = prompt("Please enter your password.").toUpperCase();
    if(user === 'KAV' && password === 'KAV') {
        alert("Hi Kav! Welcome back!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Password not valid!!! ");
    }
    break;
default:
    alert('Username not valid!!!')
}
```

The for loops were unnecessary. In my example, I exchanged document.write for alert, so that it works on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

1. Syntax error in your code at line number 26 in for loop

Semi-colon needs to be added in-between condition and incremental statement.

It is

```
for(i =0; i <0 i++)
```

It has to be

```
for(i =0; i < 0; i++)
```

2. Change the 0 to 1 in for loop

   for(i =0; i < 1; i++)

Always use the `inspect element` in any of your browser to point the error in the script.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. Thanks! But unfortunately it still doesn't work. :(